# Не выводит результат на экран

Tags: python

```
x = int(input('введите число в 10-ной: '))
a=[]
while x > 2:
        a.append(x%2)
        x//2
a.reverse()

print(a)
```

Ошибок нет, но после ввода числа ничего не происходит

Comment: `bin(your_num_in_dec).replace('0b', '')`

Comment: Поменяйте ваше `x//2` на `x = x // 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не изменяет x. Вместо `x//2` напишите `x//=2`. И все заработает:

```
x = int(input('введите число в 10-ной: '))
a=[]
while x > 2:
        a.append(x % 2)
        x //= 2
a.reverse()

print(a)
```